# display list of images in UITableview with trasparent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

Hi I want to display images in UITableview and on top of uitableview I need transparent view.

What I have tried is :

Added view in storyboard and on top of it UITableView.

```
_vaultView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:26/255.0f green:188/255.0f blue:156/255.0f alpha:0.85f];
```

Ian unable to display transparent View.

Please suggest me how to proceed further.

edit:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad]; 
        _vaultView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:26/255.0f       green:188/255.0f blue:156/255.0f alpha:0.85f];

        UILabel *lblMySaved = [self createLabelWithTitle:@"Find all your saved   work here" frame:CGRectMake(20,115,300,60) tag:1 font:[Util Font:FontTypeLight Size:18.0] color:[UIColor whiteColor] numberOfLines:0];
    [_vaultView addSubview:lblMySaved];

     _tblVault.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     _tblVault.delegate = self;
     _tblVault.dataSource = self;
     _tblVault.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [self refreshImages];
    }

     -(void)refreshImages
    {
        [aryVaultImages removeAllObjects];


       NSArray *aryImages = [self getImagesfromDB]; // Retrieving image paths   from DB
     [_tblVault reloadData];

}
        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
      return 1;
    }

     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:     (NSInteger)section
    {

    return 2;
   }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return 40;

}

      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
     {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     tableView.separatorColor =[UIColor clearColor];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
   if(indexPath.row ==0 && [aryImgPaths count])
   {
       NSLog(@"imagepath:%@",[aryImgPaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
       UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, 40, 40)];
       [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deletePost11.png"]];
       [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

   }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do? simply display the view?

Comment: yes , I want to display view on top of uitableview

Comment: you can use _vaultView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: need view background color with RGB values like _vaultView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:26/255.0f green:188/255.0f blue:156/255.0f alpha:0.85f];

Comment: for transparentView user ClearColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your Views stack in your `viewController`, you simply need to move the transparent view to the front of the stack (it is currently at the back of your `superView`).

You can do this by calling.

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:<your transparent view>];
```

And in the `storyboard` just set the view to the correct values

If you want to hide the view just call

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:<your tableView>];
```

**EDIT**

To create a transparent view on top of you `UITableView`, you need to add a `UIView` in the `storyBoard` that is a `subView` of your `viewController` main view(then set all the attributes you want in the attributes inspector). Your `tableView` need to be also a `subView` of your `viewController` main view.

*make sure that the transparent view is front of the `tableView` in your `storyBoard`

In order to handle the gestures (because the transparent view is "blocking" the gestures from the `tableView` read this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960427/passing-vertical-scrolling-gesture-to-uitableview-below))

Comment: if I add [self.view bringSubViewToFront:<your transparent view>];then cellForRowAtIndexPath not getting called

Comment: can you add your code? from what you described it's not logical to happen

Comment: when do you want your transparent view to be on top? from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section{
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) 
{
   UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
}
```